# Keyboard Only Works When Mouse Moves

Tags: keyboard, mouse

Version - Ubuntu 14.04 (also tried 13.10 and 12.10)

Machine - Lenovo R61e (Laptop)

I have been unable to determine what the problem is and I'm really hoping someone here has some suggestions.

Scenario:

- (in any text-input or word program) I press a key on the built-in Keyboard
- Nothing happens for a period of time
- After a delay, the key will input repeatedly, as if stuck or held down
- I move the mouse and it stops
- I press a key and then immediately move the mouse
- The key will input properly without repeating, but only after the mouse movement
- I plug in a USB (or wireless) Keyboard
- Keyboard inputs properly; no problems

I am stuck between thinking this is a hardware issue (which I doubt, due to no issues previously on Windows XP) and a driver issue (which I have no idea how to troubleshoot).

Does this make sense to anyone else?  Anything I can try to help narrow down the problem?

Comment: [Here is a similar problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=799119)

Comment: ^ suggests creating a new keyboard from scratch.  I deleted and set up from scratch 3 times - still no success.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try to check Keyboard - System Settings with Keyboard Repeat parameter, it may be sometimes helpful to turn it off and on again. Then please also check the Delay and Rate parameters. I have 660ms of delay and 25.00 repeats Rate by default.

Comment: I've toggled "Repeat Keys" off and on, tried with it off and numerous levels of delay/speed.  Doesn't seem to make a difference.  Additional detail noted: keyboard works fine in BIOS.